# My 520 looks bricked, with black screen. Will i still get windows 10 if i roll back using NSRT?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, lumia-520, recovery-tool

My Nokia Lumia 520 unexpectedly shut down and rebooted while i was browsing fb in **edge**. Now the only thing i get on screen is a black screen which says

> Error: Unable to find bootable option. Press any key to shut down.

i dont have another phone to take a photo of problem, but i found a similar screenshot in google, it goes like this.

[image]

Now,coming to real problem, what if i could just roll back to 8.1 using recovery tool, would i still get win 10 update?

512mb RAM devices used to get threshold updates via release preview ring, but now, all the rings are providing redstone updates, which doesn't support 512mb RAM.

Acc. to Quora, this is due to two cases, either motherboard is gone, or os boot option is corrupted, i really hope that its the 2nd case.

Hep me guys!

Answer (score 4):

I think you should first recover your phone and worry about Windows 10 later. After your phone is up again you can try the Windows Insider App and go to Release Preview Ring and see if you can get the updates. Because I think you will still be able to get the last update 10.0.10586.xxx.